# Go to next function after 5 seconds if function isn't completed, if the function is completed, stop the program

Tags: java, tensorflow

Here's my code, I'm using tensorflow object detection in ftc with android studio, but a lot of the time the camera won't pick up that there's an object in time or won't return the right variable, though I'm certain that there is an object and the camera can pick it up using the stream.

```
camera.setPosition(.40);
        sleep(500);
        telemetry.addData("runtime", getRuntime());
        while (getRuntime() <= 5 && currentRecognitions.size() == 0)  {
            if (currentRecognitions.size() == 1) {
                position = 0;
                isDetected = true;
                telemetry.addData("Position 0", isDetected);
                telemetry.update();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (getRuntime() >= 5) {
                telemetry.addData("not 0", "");
                telemetry.update();
                break;
            }
            telemetry.update();
        }
        camera.setPosition(.50);
        sleep(500);
        while (getRuntime() <= 10 && currentRecognitions.size() == 0 && getRuntime() >=5)  {
            if (currentRecognitions.size() == 1) {
                position = 1;
                isDetected = true;
                telemetry.addData("Position 1", isDetected);
                telemetry.update();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (getRuntime() >= 10) {
                telemetry.addData("not 1", "");
                telemetry.update();
                break;
            }
            telemetry.update();
        }
        camera.setPosition(.62);
        sleep(500);
        while (getRuntime() <= 15 && currentRecognitions.size() == 0 && getRuntime() >=10)  {
            if (currentRecognitions.size() == 1) {
                position = 2;
                isDetected = true;
                telemetry.addData("Position 2", isDetected);
                telemetry.update();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (getRuntime() >= 15) {
                telemetry.addData("not 2??", "");
                telemetry.update();
                break;
            }
            telemetry.update();
        }
```

I've tried adjusting the while loop and such, a lot of the time tensorflow still doesn't pick up that there's an object. I'd like to maybe run a thread counting the time while I run the if then statements, but I'm not sure how.